# when is it more correct to use to in a sentence. example, sam and ellen were married to each other or sam and ellen married each other

Tags: grammar

Sam and Elen were married to each other, or
Sam and Ellen married each other.  What is the proper usage, with or without the "to"?

Comment: They both are valid but mean different things. Please describe what you intend to mean with your sentence.

Comment: I'm being asked by a non-english person who is trying to know when to use to or not.  My answer was that Sam and Ellen were married to each other describes an action that is past, more formal, and probably in a literary or historical sense.  Sam and Ellen married each other implies a more informal reference to the marriage.  It could have happened yesterday, and it might be that you know Sam and Ellen

Comment: For the present tense, "Sam and Ellen are married to each other" works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of correctness - they're both correct, but they mean slightly different things.

In "Sam and Ellen married each other", "married" is used as a verb and denotes a specific *action* that can be qualified with an exact date and time, place and other details.

In "Sam and Elen were married to each other", in some contexts "were married" might function as a passive past tense verb, e.g. they were married by a civil celebrant, they were married in October, etc. However, the phrase "to each other" would be superfluous in this context. Retaining the phrase would probably lead a native speaker to treat "married" as an adjective, describing their *state* or condition, i.e. Sam and Ellen were spousally related to each other. The fact that the prsent tense isn't used could be interpreted to mean the condition no longer exists, i.e. they're not married to each other any more.

So the first usage would be interpreted as "Sam and Ellen got married," while the second usage could be interpreted as "Sam and Ellen used to be married to each other but they're not now." An important distinction, methinks.